# (using Python) Putting outputs into 2 lists, and pair each elements in the 2 lists

Tags: python, html, scraper

I want to work out some scripts, using Python and BeautifulSoup to pick up some texts on a webpage, and put them nicely together. they ideal results are like:

```
Port_new_cape Jan 23, 2009 12:05
Brisbane July 24, 2002 03:12
Liaoning Aug 26, 2006 02:55
```

Because the webpage is in the company website requires authentication and redirection, I copy the source code of the target page into a file and save it as `example.html` in C:\ for convenience.

Part of the source code is quoted below (they are the target paragraphs and there are many more similar paragraphs):

```
<tr class="ghj">
    <td><span class="city-sh"><sh src="./citys/1.jpg" alt="boy" title="boy" /></span><a     href="./membercity.php?mode=view&amp;u=12563">Port_new_cape</a></td>
    <td class="position"><a href="./search.php?id=12563&amp;sr=positions" title="Search     positions">452</a></td>
    <td class="details"><div>South</div></td>
    <td>May 09, 1997</td>
    <td>Jan 23, 2009 12:05 pm&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

<tr class="ghj">
    <td><span class="city-sh"><sh src="./citys/1.jpg" alt="boy" title="boy" /></span><a href="./membercity.php?mode=view&amp;u=12563">Brisbane</a></td>
    <td class="position"><a href="./search.php?id=12563&amp;sr=positions" title="Search positions">356</a></td>
    <td class="details"><div>South</div></td>
    <td>Jun 09, 1986</td>
    <td>July 24, 2002 03:12 pm&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

<tr class="ghj">
    <td><span class="city-sh"><sh src="./citys/1.jpg" alt="boy" title="boy" /></span><a href="./membercity.php?mode=view&amp;u=12563">Liaoning</a></td>
    <td class="position"><a href="./search.php?id=12563&amp;sr=positions" title="Search positions">1105</a></td>
    <td class="details"><div>Southeast</div></td>
    <td>March 09, 2007</td>
    <td>Aug 26, 2006 02:55 pm&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

So far below is what I have (Some part of the scripts thanks to a gentleman’s help.):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import urllib2

url = r"C:\example.html"
page = open(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())


#preparing the 1st list
cities = soup.find_all(href=re.compile("u="))

LST = []

for city in cities:
    ci = city.renderContents()
    full_list = LST.append(ci)


#preparing the 2nd list

Dates = soup.find_all('td', {'class' : 'info'})

LSTTT = []

counter = 0

while len(Dates) > counter:
    datesGroup = Dates[counter].find_next_siblings('td')
    if len(datesGroup) == 2:
        ti = datesGroup[1].renderContents()
        full_list_2 = LSTTT.append(ti)

    counter += 1


print full_list

print full_list_2
```

My idea is to put all the outputs into a 2 lists, and then combine each elements (they shall be correspondent one to one) in the 2 lists. However when I run the scripts, it produces 2 “NONE” lists.

My questions:

1. What went wrong in the lists? Why they are “NONE”?
2. How to combine the each elements in the 2 lists, once they are successful?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`list.append` method returns `None` as it is an inplace operation. Instead of storing the result in other variables, you can use `LSTT` and `LSTTT` as they are, like this

```
ci = city.renderContents()
LST.append(ci)
...
...
    ti = datesGroup[1].renderContents()
    LSTTT.append(ti)
...
...
print(zip(LSTT, LSTTT))
```

The `zip` function returns a list of tuples of corresponding elements of all the input iterables.

If you want to print the zipped result, withtout the tuples, you can iterate over them, like this

```
for item1, item2 in zip(LSTT, LSTTT):
    print(item1, item2)
```

Comment: thefourtheye, this is incredible! thank you. as i need to store the results seperately. is there a way not to use tuple and print them in pairs instead of write: print LST[0] + LSTTT [0]
print LST[1] + LSTTT [1]
print LST[2] + LSTTT [2]
…
print LST[-1] + LSTTT [-1]?

Comment: @MarkK You can iterate over the data like I have shown in the answer. Please check. :)